# Body title gets displayed with content

Tags: entities, nodes

I have a content type of something, with title and body only as fields, body field reporting field_body as machine name.

problem is, i create a node with content and then when it's displayed on the page, the text Body: head up the main content area, for all posts.

Tried removing the name Body from the field type name but it's a mandatory field property.

any way to rid the page of that title?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are using D7. Go to **/admin/structure/types** and select your content type.

Under the 'Manage display' tab, find the body field, and set the label to 'Hidden'. The field label will not display. You may have to repeat this for each display type (default, teaser etc.).